# Ajax response appending data

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

For some reason the following script throws error "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: commentscontainer_(post_id)".. does any one know why ? is it a syntax error ?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var msg = '.text-holder';

$('.time').timeago();
$('.text-holder').autosize();

$('#post_comment').click(function() {
    $(msg).focus();
});

$('.text-holder').keypress(function(e) {
    var postID = this.id.replace('post_', '');
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var val = $(msg).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'auth/classes/comments.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'token=<?php echo $token; ?>&msg='+escape(val),
            success: function(data) {
                $(msg).val('');
                $(msg).css('height','14px');
                $('.commentscontainer_'+postID).append(data);
                $('.time').timeago();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is pretty munch the html

```
<div class="commentscontainer_['post_id']"></div>
```

I have another script.. is it clashing with this ?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".comment_box").hide();

        $('.slider').on('click',function(){
            var flag   = $(this).data('flag'),
                postID = this.id.replace('post_', '');

            $('#' + postID).slideToggle();

            if (!flag) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'auth/classes/comments.php',
                    data: {post_id: postID}
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $('.commentscontainer_'+postID).replaceWith(data);
                    $('.time').timeago();
                });
            }
            $(this).data('flag', !flag)
        });
    });
```

Comment: The message and the token gets ajaxed fine on firebug.. throws error after the response

Comment: What is `commentscontainer`, a class, id?

Comment: Yes its a class id which contains comments..

Comment: You forgot the `.` in front of it :)

Comment: What if you remove that line, does it work?

Comment: If i remove it no error

Comment: What is `postID` after you run the `replace` function?

Comment: its a number... like 897

Comment: So, what is a live example of your HTML, `<div class="commentscontainer_[897]"></div>` like that?

Comment: <div class="commentscontainer_897"></div> like that

Comment: Right before that append statement, do `console.log('.commentscontainer_'+postID);` and comment the log.

Comment: it says .commentscontainer_"897"

Comment: There's the problem, you need to strip the quotes

Comment: Run this regex `postID = postID.replace(/['"]/g,'')`

Comment: I updated my answer, that should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the quotes from `postID` as well:

```
var postID = this.id.replace('post_', '');
postID = postID.replace(/['"]/g,'');
```

Comment: i noticed it too.. still throws the same error after correcting it

Comment: Hi,.. it doesnt throw that error.. but it doesnt append it .. nothing happens

Comment: Well what is `data`? Run `console.log(data)` and comment output please. @user2668436

Comment: response is fine.. its not getting appended

Comment: Hi.. theres another script.. if i remove it .. it gets appended.. i posted the other script to the question.. could you please have alook at it  ?

Comment: Yes, the `postID` in the other script will throw a syntax error, make sure to remove the quotes as well

Comment: still doesnt get appended

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape certain characters in your selector(like [, ]) or else jQuery will throw an error.

```
var postID = this.id.replace('post_', '');
postID = postID.replace(/\[/g,'\\[');
postID = postID.replace(/\]/g,'\\]');
```